# Spring MVC Controller Action through HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, spring, controller, action, urlconnection

I wanted to call a SPRING MVC action using HttpURLConnection, just wanted to run this as a background action.....

```
String logoutUrl = "http://www.mysite.com/logout.sho";
URL url = new URL(logoutUrl);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
etc etc....
```

The code runs perfectly fine but the action was not performed. But, if I try to perform this action using browser: http://www.mysite.com/logout.sho, it logs out me. Kindly let me know how to tackle this issue or any other way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you open a URL connection with a Java program, you're not using the same session ID as the one used by your browser, so obviously, logging out from Java doesn't log you out from the browser.

Imagine if that works, I would just need to write a program which logs out from gmail.com, and everybody gmail user would be logged out.

Answer (score 0):

It's because Spring MVC recognizes your `HttpURLConnection` as a completely separate, independent session (user). Try opening this URL in a different browser or from a different computer - obviously it won't log you out.

The reason you are not recognized is because you do not provide any session-tracking information like JSESSIONID cookie or rewritten URL. You can pass them from Java, but it's a bit of a hack. It works from your browser simply because every request to `mysite.com` includes JSESSIONID cookie transparently and Spring MVC maps it to an active session.

That being said, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I have two web apps, and I wanted to logout both apps at same time. I did the logout Web app B to A, 1st I logout to B then redirect to A and logout. This works fine as we redirect the pages. But for logout Web app A to B, the situtation is different. We don't need a redirect. It's a rest call that logout app A, then I have to create some backgroud logout procedure. Thats why I tried with calling through URL.